# Show parent and child in a separate box using CSS

Tags: css

My HMTL is :-

`<div>1</div>
    <div>1.1</div>
    <div>1.2</div>
    <div>1.2.1</div>
    <div>2</div>
        <div>2.1</div>
        <div>2.2</div>
        <div>2.2.1</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>`

Using CSS I want to show my output in separate box (like row by row). See the below link

http://jsfiddle.net/vtq3rzce/

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: I require border color as well for every div.

Comment: So, basically you want to use divs to recreate a table? What does that have to do with parent and child elements? In your code example with the divs, there don't appear to be any... (You'd have to put an element within another element.)

Comment: No, the divs are not nested, they are merely shifted...

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Niffler:- I don't want to change my HTML. It will be div only.. Only visualization should be changed using CSS.

Comment: I'm not asking you to change your HTML; I'm saying that your question doesn't make sense as it is...

Comment: Sorry I posted wrong HTML

Comment: I think I understand what you want.  I'm on it.

Comment: Here my html <div>1
  <div>1.1
   <div>1.2
    <div>1.2.1</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>2
  <div>2.1
   <div>2.2
    <div>2.2.1</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>3</div>
 <div>4</div>

Comment: How do you want it to look?  If you have sub-`div`s, how do you want them displayed?

Comment: http://oi57.tinypic.com/rm4os3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap one additional div around your nested divs, like this:

```
<div>
    <div>1
        <div>1.1
            <div>1.2
                <div>1.2.1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>2
        <div>2.1
            <div>2.2
                <div>2.2.1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Then you could do something like this to make it look something like the image in your comment:

```
div {
    width: 496px;
    border: 2px solid #4072b4;
    border-top: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 120%;
    background: #4679bd;
}

div div {
    font-size: 100%;
    width: auto;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #4072b4;
    line-height: 250%;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/qpa8db7g/

(I'm afraid I don't know how to do it with the white spacing between the elements...)

Comment: I've updated the code; can't make it exactly like your picture though, without changing the HTML...

Comment: but you set the fixed depth in the CSS. I am looking for dynamic solution.

Comment: What do you mean "fixed depth"? Do you mean the width? If that is what you mean, you can just leave that line out. This is, by the way, the first time you have mentioned something about a "dynamic solution". Next time, formulate your question better.

Comment: One more thing.... Can put a border for every div instead of background color? means no fill color in div only border.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css tables http://jsfiddle.net/vtq3rzce/1/

```
#a div {
color:green;
width:100%;
height:30px;
border:2px solid green;
display:table;
}
```

Comment: sorry post wrong html. correct html is :-  <div>1 <div>1.1 <div>1.2 <div>1.2.1</div> </div> </div> </div> <div>2 <div>2.1 <div>2.2 <div>2.2.1</div> </div> </div> </div> <div>3</div> <div>4</div>

Comment: @ManishPrajapati http://jsfiddle.net/vtq3rzce/2/ you can make it look good by changing some of its child to `display:table-row` i don't have time now search for it in w3 schools

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure exactly what you want, but you can change the `display` CSS property.

### http://jsfiddle.net/wd0tw53t/

All that I did here, is add a margin to the left of your sub-divs.

CSS:

```
div {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
div > div {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: div is always block level element my friend

Comment: No it's not.  You can change the display of any element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display